# Accessing CGImage from AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest

Tags: ios, image-processing, avfoundation

In a project recently, I had to apply filters to some videos. I have started with CIFilters which was quite straightforward, but soon I wanted to switch to something custom.

When I wanted to get the **CGImage** out of the **request** I always get **nil**. Here is the code.

```
  ^(AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest *request) {
   CGImageRef cgImage = request.sourceImage.CGImage;
  }
```

This always give nil;

Comment: Is `request.sourceImage` nil? Can you show some more code?

Comment: It is not nil. I found the solution you need draw using a context.